# How to properly set a default plot colour in pgfplots?

Tags: pgfplots

I want to set some default style options for plots with `pgfplots`. I did the following which did not give me the expected result:

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[landscape,a4paper,margin=5em]{geometry}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16} 
\usepackage{amsmath,mathtools,icomma}

\definecolor{RED}{HTML}{BE1122}

\pgfplotsset{
    every axis/.append style={
        axis lines=middle,
        every axis x label/.style={at={(current axis.right of origin)},anchor=west,overlay,fill=white},
        every axis y label/.style={at={(current axis.above origin)},anchor=south},
        xlabel={$x$},
        ylabel={$y$},
        samples=250,
        },
    every axis plot/.style={
        color=RED,
        very thick,
        no markers,
        },
    }

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}
        [
        trig format plots=rad, 
        ymin=-4.6, 
        ymax=1.6, 
        domain=-1.25:2.25,
        x post scale=2.5,
        y post scale=2,
        ticks=major,
        ticklabel style={fill=white},
        grid=major,
        ]
        \addplot {-1.5+2*sin(pi*(\x-0.5))};
        \addplot[RED, thin] {-1.5} node[pos=0.05, fill=white, anchor=north, text=RED, inner sep=0mm]{$y=-1\frac12$};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I would expect the sine function to be RED, since I set `every axis plot` to `color=red`. In stead it turn out blue. The `thin` and the `RED` in the second plot do have effect.

When I use `every axis plot post` de default does become RED, but it's then not possible to overwrite this locally.

How can I get what I want?

Also, how doe `every axis plot` and `every axis plot post` relate? I read the `pgfplots` documentation, but I find it quite cryptic.

Comment: You might want to look at `cycle list`s. Unrelated: Why do you use `\addplot plot ..`? The documented syntax is just `\addplot`.

Comment: I guess you *really* want to remove `plot` in `\addplot plot` (even if it gets ignored by the parser) because other people may look at your code and use it. And then I think your question is answered by @TorbjørnT.'s comment: define a cycle list, which may consist of only one element.